# HealthKit Elevated Heart Rate Notification Variable?

Tags: apple-watch, healthkit

Is there a specific HealthKit variable for the elevated heart rate notifications? I couldn’t find a variable in the data or object types. I am extracting data from the Apple Health app for a visualization using R and showing multiple variables from multiple wearables. I want to use the notification variable to only select heart rate data for those specific observations. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Elevated Heart Rate notifications are not accessible using the HealthKit API.

Comment: Got it. I’ll have to write some equivalent R code. Thanks.